# Laravel - Nginx - Docker - Behat combination

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, behat

I am trying to run behat inside a Nginx container in a laravel app.
My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  load_balancer:
    image: tutum/haproxy
    links:
      - nginx
    ports:
      - "8888:80"

  nginx:
    image: andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
      - ./sites:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
    links:  
      - mysql:mysql
      - redis:predis
    networks:
      - front-tier
      - back-tier
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=local
      - DB_DATABASE=homestead
      - DB_PASSWORD=secret
      - DB_HOST=mysql

  artisan:
    image: spiralout/dartisan
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
      - redis:predis
    networks:
      - front-tier
      - back-tier

  mysql:
    image: spiralout/alpine-mariadb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - back-tier

  composer:  
    image: spiralout/dcomposer
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
    networks:
      - back-tier

  nodejs:  
    image: spiralout/dnodejs
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
    networks:
      - back-tier

  redis:
    image: spiralout/alpine-redis
    volumes:
      - ./redis-data:/data
    networks:
      - back-tier

volumes:
  www:
  sites:
  redis-data:

networks:
  front-tier:
  back-tier:
```

What I do after is

```
docker-compose up -d
```

and then

```
docker exec -it <nginx_name> \bin\bash
```

I then try to run behat

```
vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat
```

My test simply tries to visit and print the homepage.
FeatureContext.php

```
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
     * context constructor through behat.yml.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @Given that I am on the homepage
     */
    public function thatIAmOnTheHomepage()
    {
        $this->iAmOnHomepage();
        $this->visit("https://localhost:80");
        $this->printLastresponse();
    }

    /**
     * @Given that name is :arg1
     */
    public function thatNameIs($arg1)
    {
        $this->fillField('name', $arg1);
    }

    /**
     * @Given that email is :arg1
     */
     public function thatEmailIs($arg1)
     {
        $this->fillField('email', $arg1);
     }

    /**
     * @When you try to register
     */
     public function youTryToRegister()
    {
        $this->pressButton('registerButton');
    }

    /**
     * @Then you remain on the homepage
     */
    public function youRemainOnTheHomepage()
    {
        assertUrlRegExp('http://localhost');
    }
}
```

The problems are that I can't access the web app, I only get nginx homepage
And secondly my app trying to visit it just get's page not found.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you access the web app manually? try to check/echo/print the url to see if is ok. MinkContext should already have the snippet for navigating to the homepage, you can override that method.Also make sure you have the base_url in behat.yml of custom yml config file.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to create a new project with the dev-develop flag.
`composer create-project laravel/laravel new dev-develop`

For some reason Mink-Extension wasn't working correctly for me without the flag